# How to allow users to specify slide number and URL adress from which to load content with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slider

Is there a way to allow users to specify how many slides they want the slider to have. As well as from which HTML page they want the content to be loaded in each slide using an AJAX call in jQuery.

Because the slide i made uses the jQuery `.load()` call to load content into each specific slide whenever it comes into view, and sets the `window.location.hash` to a certain value for each slide; I would like the users to be able to specify the values for these two things.

In other words specify the URL address the `.load()` method pulls for each slide, as well as what the hash tag will be when each slide shows.

The `.load()` URL address is meant to be different for each slide as well as the hash tag.

So for example: Slide to slide number two, the content from a url specified only for slide two is loaded and the hash tag is changed to some user specified value.

Slide to slide number three, the content from a url specified value for slide three is loaded, and hash tag is changed to some other user specified value.

Is there a way to achieve these things by allowing the user to chose the amount of slides they want to have instead of having a set amount of slides?

Also is there a way to have the user specifications sorted in a array such as:

```
    var slideshash = ["#userSpecifiedHash1", "#userSpecifiedHash2"];
```

If anybody can give me an idea how this can be done, or if its possible; or direct me to an article or tutorial related to this, i would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find path.js routing library to be extremely helpful in situations like you explained.  Loading certain content and calling functions based on urls/hash tags is made easy...

There are a few samples located on the project GitHub @ [HERE](https://github.com/mtrpcic/pathjs)

Edits:

I'm not too sure on your logic behind your hashes but here is how I would do it with PathJS and jQuery.  Keep in mind that in this example, we are simply adding more routes and not taking them away...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var slidehash = new Array();

    function go(){  
            Path.map(slidehash[0]).to(function(){
                alert("#1 hash found: "+slidehash[0]);
            });
            Path.map(slidehash[1]).to(function(){
                alert("#2 hash found: "+slidehash[1]);
            });
            Path.map(slidehash[2]).to(function(){
                alert("#3 hash found: "+slidehash[2]);
            });
        Path.listen();
    }

    $(function() {  
        $('#save').click(function() {
            slidehash[0]=$(".changeMe:eq(0)").val();
            slidehash[1]=$(".changeMe:eq(1)").val();
            slidehash[2]=$(".changeMe:eq(2)").val();
            go();           
        });

    });
    </script>
<ul id="inputList">
    <li><input class="changeMe" type="text" value="#/test"></li>
    <li><input class="changeMe" type="text" value=""></li>
    <li><input class="changeMe" type="text" value=""></li>
</ul>
<p><input id="save" type="button" value="Assign hashbang!" /></p>
</script>
```

Comment: i think i was maybe misunderstood, i have already written an app which runs events based on hash changes and loads content using an ajax call. But what i want is a way to allow the end user runing the app on their domain to change the urls being loaded and the names of the hashtags through a UI instead of having to go into the code.

Comment: I'm still not sure if I follow.  Here is what I understand:  A user slides the slider and ajax calls separate pieces of content on the page depending on the slider position.  You want the hash location to update as the different pieces of content are loaded (on each position of the slider)?

Comment: oh no i already have a slider that does all the things you described, im sorry if i was misunderstood. What i want now is to allow someone implementing it to be able to specify which url is being loaded in the ajax and what the hash tag is change to, from a User interface or something similar, without having to go into to the code, like an end product. Basically a slider which can be changed form an UI. I hope i made sense now :)

Comment: I didn't use a slider but added a few editable inputs that allow you to add new routings.  Should be a similar concept...

Comment: oh yes thank you very much, this is certainly what i was looking for, sorry for not being clear enough, you've shown me in which direction to go, thank you :D